# Spark SQL query filter behavior with special character $ in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using the below Spark SQL query, however it doesn't return any records unless I escape the "$" character in the condition.

My table has rows with the value "$AG72i$GE" in the column.

The below query is not returning any results,

```sql
select * from mytable where col1 = '$AG72i$GE'
```

while the following is returning results as expected.

```sql
select * from mytable where col1 = '\$AG72i\$GE'
```

Is this expected behaviour in Spark? I tried to search the documentation, but didn't find anywhere it is mentioned to escape $ char for equality filter.

We use Databricks 9.1 version which has Spark 3.1.2. We could reproduce the issue on Databricks 10 too. The underling data is in delta format but really are parquet files.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? What system do you have that uses Spark? I cannot reproduce your issue (the filter works fine without escaping)

Comment: We use Databricks 9.1 version which has spark 3.1.2. We could reproduce the issue on Databricks 10 also. The joins or sub queries are working fine, but only when filtering with hard coded value, we need to escape. I have opened a Databricks support case and they confirmed escaping the $ character is the only option now.  By the way, the underling data is in delta format but really are parquet files.

Comment: Thanks. You could answer this question yourself and share the support ticket reference.